# Python count occurence of a string without overlapping from a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I was trying to find the occurrence of every 2 consecutive characters from a string.
The result will be in a `dictionary` as `key = 2 characters`  and `value = number of occurrence`.

I tried the following :

```
seq = "AXXTAGXXXTA"

d = {seq[i:i+2]:seq.count(seq[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(seq)-1)}
```

The problem is that the result of `XX` should be `3` not `2` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

seq = "AXXTAGXXXTA"

Counter((seq[i:i+2] for i in range(len(seq)-1)))
```

Output:

```
Counter({'AX': 1, 'XX': 3, 'XT': 2, 'TA': 2, 'AG': 1, 'GX': 1})
```

*Or without additional libraries.* You can use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault).

```
seq = "AXXTAGXXXTA"

d = {}
for i in range(len(seq)-1):
    key = seq[i:i+2]
    d[key] = d.setdefault(key, 0) + 1
print(d)
```

Comment: Can this be achieved using same syntax that I mentioned above ?

Comment: @BouhaaCode, can you explain more? what do you syntaxt want?

Comment: I meant without using additional libraries if possible.

Comment: @BouhaaCode, edited, see the second part.